# pandas pivot table : trouble with dividing by sum of rows

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I am having trouble using a a pivot table with columns names in pandas.

here my problem

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd


table = OrderedDict((
("Item", ['Item0', 'Item0', 'Item1', 'Item1']),
('CType',['Gold', 'Bronze', 'Gold', 'Silver']),
('USD',  [1, 2, 3, 4]),
('EU',   [1, 2, 3, 4])
))
d = pd.DataFrame(table)

print d

p = d.pivot_table(index='Item', columns='CType', values='USD')
print p

p.fillna(0, inplace=True)
print p
```

**The following operation gives me NaN in a weird shape.** 
What am I missing ?

```
 p / p.sum(axis = 1)
```

P.S: the example of the data is taken from [here](http://nikgrozev.com/2015/07/01/reshaping-in-pandas-pivot-pivot-table-stack-and-unstack-explained-with-pictures/) but my own data show same behaviour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DF.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) instead:

```
p.div(p.sum(1), 0)
```

[image]

`axis=1` in the afore-mentioned method behaves in the similar manner as the way you've done before resulting in all `Nans`.

You have to make it compute row-wise(along the index) by supplying `axis=0`.

Comment: thanks Nickil. This is great and works as expected. Am still wondering however how to deal with "named columns" which come from pivot operations. Will post a separate question